# Parse JSON using Python?

Tags: bash, python, json

#### I have a JSON file `members.json` as below.

```
{
   "took": 670,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 8,
      "successful": 8,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 74,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "2000_270_0",
            "_type": "Medical",
            "_id": "02:17447847049147026174478:174159",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf",
               "memberFirstName": "Uri",
               "memberMiddleName": "Prayag",
               "memberLastName": "Dubofsky"
            }
         }, 
         {
            "_index": "2000_270_0",
            "_type": "Medical",
            "_id": "02:17447847049147026174478:174159",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG",
               "memberFirstName": "Uri",
               "memberMiddleName": "Prayag",
               "memberLastName": "Dubofsky"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to parse it using `bash` script get only the list of field `memberId`.

#### The expected output is:

```
memberIds
----------- 
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG
```

#### I tried adding following bash+python code to `.bashrc`:

```
function getJsonVal() {
   if [ \( $# -ne 1 \) -o \( -t 0 \) ]; then
       echo "Usage: getJsonVal 'key' < /tmp/file";
       echo "   -- or -- ";
       echo " cat /tmp/input | getJsonVal 'key'";
       return;
   fi;
   cat | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["'$1'"]';
}
```

And then called:

```
$ cat members.json | getJsonVal "memberId"
```

But it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'memberId'
```

#### Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21595107/432903

Comment: Why do you need to do this in bash? you are clearly using python here so why not just create a python script that does the job? You might not get actual answers on how to do it with bash because when you need to do that much you use another language.

Comment: I changed your title from *"using bash script"* to *"using python"* since `python`, and not `bash`, is what you are using to parse json.  E.g., that error is certainly a python error, not a bash error.

Comment: @goldilocks just because his attempt used `python`, doesn't mean his goal is to use `python`

Comment: @DavidG see my answer. It's not pure shell, it's an external command but it integrates into shell scripts pretty well.

Comment: Can I suggest you take out most of the irrelevant fields in the json. It suffices to have 2-3 elements in _source to get the gist of what you try to do. The rest just distracts

Comment: @jonrdanm I stand corrected, that tool seems simple enough that you don't need to switch to another language. I actually think your answer with `jshon` is the best since it is meant to be used from the shell.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you would use:

```
 $ cat members.json | \
     python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj;'
```

you can inspect the structure of the nested dictonary `obj` and see that your original line should read:

```
$ cat members.json | \
    python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["'$1'"]';
```

to the to that "memberId" element. This way you can keep the Python as a oneliner.

If there are multiple elements in the nested "hits" element, then you can do something like:

```
$ cat members.json | \
python -c '
import json, sys
obj=json.load(sys.stdin)
for y in [x["_source"]["'$1'"] for x in obj["hits"]["hits"]]:
    print y
'
```

Chris Down's solution is better for finding a single value to (unique) keys at any level.

With my second example that prints out multiple values, you are hitting the limits of what you should try with a one liner, at that point I see little reason why to do half of the processing in bash, and would move to a complete Python solution.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do this in bash is using [jshon](https://github.com/keenerd/jshon). Here is a solution to your problem using `jshon`:

```
$ jshon -e hits -e hits -a -e _source -e memberId -u < foo.json
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG
```

The `-e` options extract values from the json. The `-a` iterates over the array and the `-u` decodes the final string.

Comment: Let me install jshon

Answer (score 7):

Well, your key is quite clearly not at the root of the object. Try something like this:

```
json_key() {
    python -c '
import json
import sys

data = json.load(sys.stdin)

for key in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        data = data[key]
    except TypeError:  # This is a list index
        data = data[int(key)]

print(data)' "$@"
}
```

This has the benefit of not just simply injecting syntax into Python, which could cause breakage (or worse, arbitrary code execution).

You can then call it like this:

```
json_key hits hits 0 _source memberId < members.json
```

Comment: Note: This will not loop over each item in "hits". If you want that, you should write specific Python code for that instance.

Comment: But it shows only one memberId.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ cat members.json | jq -r '.hits|.hits|.[]|._source|.memberId'
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ cat json.txt | python -c 'import sys; import simplejson as json; \
print "\n".join( [i["_source"]["memberId"] for i in json.loads( sys.stdin.read() )["hits"]["hits"]] )'
```

---

If you already have `pretty printed` json, why don't you just `grep` it?

```
$ cat json.txt | grep memberId
               "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf",
               "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG",
```

You can always get a pretty printed format with simplejson python to `grep` it.

```
# cat json_raw.txt
{"hits": {"hits": [{"_score": 1, "_type": "Medical", "_id": "02:17447847049147026174478:174159", "_source": {"memberLastName": "Dubofsky", "memberMiddleName": "Prayag", "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf", "memberFirstName": "Uri"}, "_index": "2000_270_0"}, {"_score": 1, "_type": "Medical", "_id": "02:17447847049147026174478:174159", "_source": {"memberLastName": "Dubofsky", "memberMiddleName": "Prayag", "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG", "memberFirstName": "Uri"}, "_index": "2000_270_0"}], "total": 74, "max_score": 1}, "_shards": {"successful": 8, "failed": 0, "total": 8}, "took": 670, "timed_out": false}
```

Use dumps:

```
# cat json_raw.txt | python -c 'import sys; import simplejson as json; \
print json.dumps( json.loads( sys.stdin.read() ), sort_keys=True, indent=4); '

{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 8,
        "total": 8
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "02:17447847049147026174478:174159",
                "_index": "2000_270_0",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "memberFirstName": "Uri",
                    "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf",
                    "memberLastName": "Dubofsky",
                    "memberMiddleName": "Prayag"
                },
                "_type": "Medical"
            },
            {
                "_id": "02:17447847049147026174478:174159",
                "_index": "2000_270_0",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "memberFirstName": "Uri",
                    "memberId": "0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG",
                    "memberLastName": "Dubofsky",
                    "memberMiddleName": "Prayag"
                },
                "_type": "Medical"
            }
        ],
        "max_score": 1,
        "total": 74
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 670
}
```

Thereafter, simply `grep` result with 'memberId' pattern.

To be completely precise:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"
cat $filename | python -c 'import sys; import simplejson as json; \
print json.dumps( json.loads( sys.stdin.read() ), sort_keys=True, indent=4)' | \
grep memberId | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/^"//g' | sed -e 's/",$//g'
```

Usage:

```
$ bash bash.sh json_raw.txt 
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1920585/2821963) I'd use json.tool in python:

`python -m json.tool members.json | awk -F'"' '/memberId/{print $4}'`

Answer (score 0):

Using [deepdiff](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff) you do not need to know the exact keys:

```
import json
from deepdiff import DeepSearch
DeepSearch(json.load(open("members.json", "r")), 'memberId', verbose_level=2)['matched_paths'].values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash solution.

1. create file `find_members.sh`
2. add the following line to file + save

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   echo -e "\nmemberIds\n---------"
   cat members.json | grep -E 'memberId'|awk '{print$2}' | cut -d '"' -f2
   ```
3. `chmod +x find_members.sh`

Now run it:

```
$ ./find_members.sh

memberIds
----------------
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcf
0x7b93910446f91928e23e1043dfdf5bcG
```